# ASP.NET MVC flow question

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is there any article that introduces the complete flow of round-trip requests to MVC-based web sites. For example, when OnActionExecuting (under Controller) will be executed during the request life cycle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/20/aspnet-mvc-pipeline-lifecycle/

there are a few useful ones here too on MVC: http://devcheatsheet.com/tag/aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman explains a littlebit in his [ASP.NET MVC2 demo](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman).